# what is the easiest way to calculate last month in current yearly quarter

Tags: c#

in c#, i want a function to take current date and return the number of the last month of that quarter of the year (as a 2 character string)

So

- on Jan 1st it would return 03 (For March)
- on Dec 12, it would return 12 (For Dec)
- on Feb 25, it would return 03 (For march)

something like this:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(
    DateTime.Today.Year,
    DateTime.Today.Month,
    DateTime.Today.Day);

String 2characterlastMonthinQuarter = CalcLastMonthInQuarter(dt);
```

Comment: It depends on how you define a quarter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public static int CalcLastMonthInQuarter(DateTime dt)
{
    return 3 * ((dt.Month - 1) / 3 + 1);
}

public static string CalcLastMonthInQuarterStr(DateTime dt)
{
    return CalcLastMonthInQuarter(dt).ToString("00");
}
```

Here, this test:

```
for(int month = 1; month <= 12; ++month)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", month, CalcLastMonthInQuarterStr(new DateTime(2011, month, 1)));
}
```

prints:

```
1: 03
2: 03
3: 03
4: 06
5: 06
6: 06
7: 09
8: 09
9: 09
10: 12
11: 12
12: 12
```

Answer (score 2):

```
((DateTime.Now.Month + 2) / 3 * 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming standard quarter-end dates. I strongly prefer not doing ugly arithmetic here. It's more readable and maintable. To wit:

```
public static string LastMonthOfQuarterAsString(DateTime date) {
    return String.Format("{0:00}", LastMonthOfQuarter(date));
}

private static int LastMonthOfQuarter(DateTime date) {
    int year = date.Year;
    DateTime[] endOfQuarters = new[] {
        new DateTime(year, 3, 31),
        new DateTime(year, 6, 30),
        new DateTime(year, 9, 30),
        new DateTime(year, 12, 31)
    };
    DateTime quarterEndForDate = endOfQuarters.First(d => date <= d);
    return quarterEndForDate.Month;                
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this approach is efficient?

Comment: @Vlad: Are you sure it's not?

Comment: @Vlad: I bet it's not a bottleneck. And I bet if it is, it's trivial to overcome (the bottleneck will be the array creation, so you just memoize it).

Comment: @Saeb: no, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: @Vlad: Exactly. Worry about readability and maintenance when writing code. Optimize after you have a working solution and you are _sure_ that you have found the bottleneck.

Comment: @Saeb: I am concerned that such an approach may turn into "use bubble sort and arrays as containers, ask clients to buy a better CPU" :)

Comment: I don’t see that much _readability_ in this code (“d => date <= d”? LOL!). With a comparable amount of code, you could write a simple arithmetic routine, plus a full unit test, which is IMHO often the most readable access to a piece of code. Your solution is more general, I’ll grant you that.

Comment: @Mormegil: You're joking (or biased), right? The code basically reads as take the first end-of-quarter date that comes after the current date.

Comment: @Saeb, @Jason: My simple profiling shows that the inner function of your method vs. the answer above is 15 times slower: [1.83s](http://ideone.com/XFfBD) vs. [0.12s](http://ideone.com/83ADj). Converting the result into string is really slow and makes the fast variant win only at 2:1.

Comment: @Jason: IMHO the arithmetical solution is more readable, too (maybe because I'm a mathematician), but tastes differ.

Comment: @JAson: `endOfQuarters` depends on `year`, so in the current code state you cannot precalculate it.

Comment: @Vlad: I'm schooled in math also. This reads like what it is doing, the math solution does not. Also you can memoize so that subsequent calls are fast. This is all for naught if it's not even a bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String CalcLastMonthInQuarter(DateTime dt)
{
    return (Math.Ceiling(dt.Month / 3D) * 3).ToString("00");
}
```